# Should I say "education resources" or "educational resources"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

In the following sentence:

> The stagnation in the educational process in middle east is quasi attributed to the deficit in the budget allotted to the education resources.

Should it have been "*...allotted to the education resources.*" or "*....allotted to the educational resources.*"?

Comment: The ratio of Google hits for "educational resources" : "education resources" : "quasi attributed" is 11 500 000 : 3 900 000 : 310 (and most of those 310 look dodgy). Middle East. allocated?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would say that they're different and can mean very different things. It depends on the context.

For the quote you provided an ***educational resource*** could be things like books, supplies for the classroom, and various other resources that aid the learning process or make it possible to educate.

An ***education resource*** could be something quite different.  It would include opportunities for education from kindergarten to college, from vocational training to specialization within a field of research.